# iOS code to detect if device is level

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, swift

I'd like to write an app that detects if the person is holding an iPhone or iPad level, or if they have the device angled somewhere along the x/y/z axis and at what angle it is at.  I've seen many apps that provide similar functionality, but not much code.

Can someone point me to an online tutorial, or provide code that demonstrates these capabilities?

Comment: Motiongraphs sample code in xcode/apple documentation is what you want!

Comment: @timothykc I think you mean [Core Motion](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CoreMotion_Reference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009686)?

Comment: Nope. Coremotion is the framework, but [motiongraphs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/samplecode/MotionGraphs/Introduction/Intro.html) is a sample app that visualizes CoreMotion data nicely in realtime. He wanted sample code :)

Comment: And remember you can't run it in simulator--you need to run it on a device ;)

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I was looking for!  Thank-you.  Can you post it as an answer so I can credit your response?

Comment: Great, and hope it helps!

Answer (score 4):

Coremotion is the relevant framework. [motiongraphs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/samplecode/MotionGraphs/Introduction/Intro.html) is a great sample app that visualizes CoreMotion data nicely in realtime.

Answer (score 0):

As @timothykc noted, the MotionGraphs sample is a great example of using the CoreMotion library.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/MotionGraphs/Introduction/Intro.html

Another nice example:

http://www.captechconsulting.com/blog/john-morrison/ios-getting-started-accelerometer-data

Here are the highlights:

1) Use a singleton pattern for accessing the CMMotionManager (this snippet is straight from the sample project).

```
@interface AppDelegate ()
{
    CMMotionManager *motionmanager;
}
@end

@implementation AppDelegate
- (CMMotionManager *)sharedManager
{
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        motionmanager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
    });
    return motionmanager;
}
@end
```

2) Use this code to register for updates to the pitch/roll/yaw:

```
CMMotionManager *mManager = [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] sharedManager];

APLDeviceMotionGraphViewController * __weak weakSelf = self;

if ([mManager isDeviceMotionAvailable] == YES) {
    [mManager setDeviceMotionUpdateInterval:0.1];
    [mManager startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] withHandler:^(CMDeviceMotion *deviceMotion, NSError *error)
    {
        //Access the pitch, roll, and yaw from the attitude and do something with them.
        //deviceMotion.attitude.yaw
        //deviceMotion.attitude.roll
        //deviceMotion.attitude.pitch
    }];
}
```